# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, sql

i'm coding a project and have some troubles when the system inform error:
 Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in:
 foreach($dbh->query($q1) as $row)

and can't get data from the database. How can i fix it, im a newbie, so if i don't understand, please teach me! thanks!
thank for your helps but i still can't fix it

```
<?php include("top.html"); ?>

<body>

    <div id="main">
        <h1>Results for <?php echo $_GET['firstname'] . " " . $_GET['lastname'] ?></h1> <br/><br/>
        <div id="text">All Films</div><br/>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="index">#</td>
                <td class="title">Title</td>
                <td class="year">Year</td>
            </tr>
            <?php

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=imdb_small', 'root', '');


    $q1 = "SELECT id 
            FROM actors 
            WHERE first_name = '".$_GET['firstname']."'  AND last_name = '".$_GET['lastname']."' 
            AND film_count >= all(SELECT film_count 
                                    FROM actors 
                                    WHERE (first_name LIKE'".$_GET['firstname']." %' OR first_name = '".$_GET['firstname']."') 
                                    AND last_name = '".$_GET['lastname']."')";
    $id = null;

    foreach($dbh->query($q1) as $row){
        $id = $row['id']    ;
    }
    if($id == null){
        echo "Actor ".$_GET['firstname']." ".$_GET['lastname']."not found.";  
    }
    `
                $sql2 = "SELECT m.name, m.year 
                 FROM movies m 
                 JOIN roles r ON r.movie_id = m.id 
                 JOIN actors a ON r.actor_id = a.id 
                 WHERE (r.actor_id='".$id."') 
                 ORDER BY m.year DESC, m.name ASC";

            $i = 0;
            foreach($dbh->query($sql2) as $row){
                echo "<tr><td class=\"index\">";
                echo $i+1;
                echo "</td><td class=\"title\">";
                echo $row['name'];
                echo "</td><td class=\"year\">";
                echo $row['year'];
                echo "</td></tr>";
                $i++;
            }
            $dbh = null;
            ?>

        </table>

    </div>
</div>
<?php include("bottom.html"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using PDO, for the love of sanity, use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: You don't check that your query succeeds, you just assert it does. It seems not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your query succeeded before iterating on the result:

```
if (false !== ($result = $dbh->query($d1))) {
    foreach($result as $row){
        $id = $row['id']    ;
    }
}
```

By the way, I don't understand what you are trying to do with this pointless loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
$st = $dbh->query($q1);
if ( $st ) {
    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {}
}
```

> Try to make your code more readable

Comment: According to documentation, `fetch()` method is not mandatory: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php (see example 1). The error may rather be because query fails and returns FALSE instead of a PDOStatement.

Comment: Your edited answer will not work if the query fails... Calling `fetch()` on `FALSE` cannot work. Here, you assume `$st` is a `PDOStatement`, which seems to not be the case.

Comment: Unless i read the question poorly @Arcesilas but i think the question was but him getting an error in the form of Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in: foreach($dbh->query($q1) as $row) not neccesary about his query failing. I could be wrong

Comment: The only reason that `$dbh->query()` cannot be a valid argument for `foreach`, is that it's not a `PDOStatement`. If query succeeds, it returns a `PDOStatement` which can **ALWAYS** be used in `foreach`. If query fails, it returns `FALSE`. No that hard...

Comment: Maybe my latest edited answer could help address that @Arcesilas

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = $dbh->query($q1);

foreach($result as $row){$id = $row['id'];}
```

Comment: If query fails, `$result` will be `FALSE`. And the error will be the same.

Comment: This is no different than what OP has. You just stored the results in `$result` instead of directly injecting them into the loop.